# React Native Simple Calculation Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am learning React Native. Made 1 2 apps.
Now in my third app I need to make some arithmetic operations. It is very simple.
Like `100 * 4.31 and 100 * 4.41`

```
console.log(100 * 4.31)
console.log(100 * 4.41)
```

**Output**

```
430.99999999999994
441
```

Out put should be 4.31 in first log but it is not.

Can anyone find me a solution what is wrong with this simple arithmetic operation in React Native?

Comment: It's not react native problem. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use toFixed() function for rounding off the result of arithmetic expressions like this

```js
console.log(Number((100 * 4.31).toFixed(2)));

console.log(Number((100 * 4.41).toFixed(2)));
```

Anyway its just a JavaScript simple problem, not a specific of React Native.

Comment: Yes, I have tested this in JavaScript after you mention in your answer. But why it is still there I mean isn't this big issue for some of calculations? Curious to know..

Comment: Basically its the result of calculation which you will get from a scientific calculator. So, in reality it's not a problem but the correct result of calculation. What you want to do is limiting the result to a limited number of digits.